# requireJS method calling in define

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I need to know 2 doubts in using requireJS.

My Code:

**1. Index.html**

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

**2.main.js**

```
require(['../page1', '../global'], function(View,global){    
var v = new View();
v.init();  

var g = new global();
g.getlanguage();  
});
```

**3.page1.js**

```
define([], function (require) {
 var view1 = function(){
  this.init = function(){
    $('.page__submit').on('click', function(e) {
          view1.new_submit();
          e.preventDefault();
        });
  },
   this.new_submit = function(){
   alert("new submit in..");
  }
};
return view1;
});
```

***Question 1***: In **page1.js** onclick `view1.new_submit();` is not working. how to call the method?
***Question 2***: I have initialized `**global**` in `**main.js**`, But i couldn't access the global inside the **`page1.js`**. 
Please help.

Comment: Regarding Q1: have you checked the console and are executing the JS after the DOM has loaded? regarding Q2: just pass the "global" object as a parameter to the constructor. Currently there is no way your view can access a variable from another scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Question 1**, you just need to address how you are accessing `this`, so I made a reference using `self` that should allow you to call on itself in the below example code.

For **Question 2**, you need to require the `global` module in your `page1` module so you can use it, so I've added the dependency. Please note you may need to alter the path of `../global` to match your relative structure. Please see edit for alternative approach to this question.

```
define(['../global'], function (g) {

    var view1 = function() {
        var self = this;

        self.init = function() {
            console.log(g.getLanguage());

            $('.page__submit').on('click', function(e) {
                self.new_submit();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        },

        self.new_submit = function() {
            alert("new submit in..");
        }
    };

    return view1;
});
```

**EDIT** or alternatively for **Question 2**, you could add `global` as an argument to `init` of the `View`, but this is **dependent on how you want to actually use the module**. It would look like this: -

Inside *main.js*

```
var g = new global();
g.getlanguage();

var v = new View();
v.init(g);
```

Inside *page1.js*

```
self.init = function (g) { // g is the module reference
    console.log(g.getLanguage());

    $('.page__submit').on('click', function(e) {
        self.new_submit();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
},
```

**And finally** I would like to mention that having a module called *global* might confuse future developers who pick up that code. I'm not sure what the modules responsibility would be, but consider renaming it to be clearer.

Alternatively you may be looking to actually make this global for some reason. In this case, just attach it to the window object by assigning it in `main.js`, which would go like `window.global = g;` just afer your `g.getLanguage();`. It may be wise to make `global` some defined object prior to the Require JS init in its own script file, for example, defining it as a global variable before the require script tag: -

```
<script src="js/global-module.js"></script>
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

And tweaking your global module to ensure it is generic (and therefore clear you intend it not to be AMD): -

```
var global = {
    property: 'value',
    myFunction: function () {
        // etc.. Don't know what format you want or what is in global.
    }
};

window.global = global;
```

**PS** if you are making `global` a global variable, then consider namespacing it to avoid collisions with other code, e.g. `myAppNameGlobalModule` instead of just `global`.

Comment: Thanks @Owen Ayres . Do i need to add the dependency path on each page.? is it possible to set as a global variable ?

Comment: @GaneshKumar See the edit I did at the bottom just now haha - it addresses that. Although I would recommend defining global as a non-AMD module if this what you are wanting, as that is also likely to keep your intentions for the module a little clearer.

Comment: @GaneshKumar Brilliant. No problem!